# WordPress $wpdb get_results() not getting all records

Tags: wordpress

When i added “LIMIT 0,1000″ at the end of the query and that seemed to work. We increased the limit to 5000, that failed $wpdb get_results() query.

But what we found was that when $wpdb->get_results() was replaced with mysql_query(), the query used to work fine.

Comment: Show your query please!

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM `product_detail` WHERE 1 AND `status` LIKE 'publish' LIMIT 0,5000";
$wpdb -> get_results ($wpdb -> prepare($query));

Comment: Limit 0,5000 giving 0 result or giving some result atleast?

Comment: giving 0 results....means my page was blank display.......

Comment: Have you tried by making `wp_debug` to `true` ?

Comment: yes...i have try this

Comment: What error is it giving ?

Comment: Anything in your logs?  It might be a memory issue

Comment: yes...this is the memory issue....

Answer (score 0):

However, after doing some R & D, I found that the failure is due to the memory_limit setting in php.ini. The amount of memory consumed was too much for the big result set.so memory_limit value set the 256Mb.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring $wpdb as global and using it to execute an SQL query statement that returns a PHP object

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM product_detail WHERE 1 AND status LIKE 'publish' LIMIT 0,5000', OBJECT );
```